# Using a lookup table with Laravel's Eloquent ORM: not unique table alias?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been trying to use Eloquent for an application I'm making (being proted from Codeigniter) but I can't get it to work.

I have 3 tables:

- `users`
- `departments`
- `department_members` (this is the lookup table)

`department_members` has 3 fields: id, department_id and user_id. All my tables have their own models. When I try to use the ORM to get the department of an user (`User::find(1)->member()->first()`) all I get is this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'users'

Although I know what the problem is, I don't know how to solve it, since it's all generated by the ORM.

The models:

- Member model

  ```
  class Member extends Eloquent {
      public static $table        = 'department_members';
      public static $timestamps   = false;

      public function user() {
          return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('User', 'users');
      }
  }
  ```
- User model

  ```
  class User extends Eloquent {
      public static $timestamps = false;

      public function member() {
          return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Member', 'department_members');
      }
  }
  ```
- Department model

  ```
  class Department extends Eloquent {
      public function member() {
          return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Member', 'department_members');
      }
  }
  ```

The columns have appropiate names: id as PK, and the respective names with _id appended.

If more info is needed I would be happy to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've setup your relationships incorrectly. You don't need to have a member model - just a User, and Department model.

Like so:

```
# in User
public function departments() {
    return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Department', 'department_members');
}

# in Department
public function users() {
    return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('User', 'department_members');
}
```

There's no need for the additional model. Additionally, you might want to read here: http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#many-to-many - of special note is the pivot tables, in case you want to do some extra work on the join table aspect of the relationship.

Comment: Exactly — `department_members` was my pivot table and Eloquent generates the correct query using it without actually declaring it (aside from that second param). I just need to define start table and end table, not middle table. Thanks!